# How to change this message to an embed message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to change this part into an embed message

```
message.channel.send(`${client.player.getQueue(message).loopMode ? '(looped)' : ''}\nCurrent: **__${queue.playing.author} | ${queue.playing.title}__** \n\n` + (queue.tracks.map((track, i) => {
            return `**${i + 1})** ${track.author} - ${track.title} | ${track.requestedBy.username}`
        }).slice(0, 10).join('\n') + `\n\n${queue.tracks.length > 10 ? `And **${queue.tracks.length - 10}** more track(s)` : `   **This is the end of the queue!**`}`));
```

I already try to change it into embed but it seems not working

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'queue',
    aliases: ['q'],
    category: 'Music',
    utilisation: '{prefix}queue',

    execute(client, message) {

        const queue = client.player.getQueue(message);

        message.channel.send(`${client.player.getQueue(message).loopMode ? '(looped)' : ''}\nCurrent: **__${queue.playing.author} | ${queue.playing.title}__** \n\n` + (queue.tracks.map((track, i) => {
            return `**${i + 1})** ${track.author} - ${track.title} | ${track.requestedBy.username}`
        }).slice(0, 10).join('\n') + `\n\n${queue.tracks.length > 10 ? `And **${queue.tracks.length - 10}** more track(s)` : `   **This is the end of the queue!**`}`));
    },
};
```

Comment: What discord.js version are you on? This would help me frame an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create an embed normally [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed) || [guides](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview)

```js
const discord = require('discord.js')
const embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
.setDescription(`${client.player.getQueue(message).loopMode ? '(looped)' : ''}\nCurrent: **__${queue.playing.author} | ${queue.playing.title}__** \n\n` + (queue.tracks.map((track, i) => {
            return `**${i + 1})** ${track.author} - ${track.title} | ${track.requestedBy.username}`
        }).slice(0, 10).join('\n') + `\n\n${queue.tracks.length > 10 ? `And **${queue.tracks.length - 10}** more track(s)` : `   **This is the end of the queue!**`}`));

message.channel.send(embed)

// if you're on v13 use this:
// message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick primer on using embeds with discord.js

```js
const embed = new MessageEmbed() // you create an embed like this
  .setTitle("awesome embed title") // you set a title like this
  .setDescription("some snazzy description here") // you set a description like this
  .addFields([
    {
      name: "field name here",
      value: "field value here"
    },
    {
      name: "field name here",
      value: "field value here"
    }
  ]) // you add fields like this
  .addField("name", "value"); // or you can add a single field like this

// and you send it like this
message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] }); // message.channel.send(embed) if you're on discord.js v12
```

So in your case, it would probably be something like

```js
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle(`Queue ${client.player.getQueue(message).loopMode ? "(looped)" : ""}`)
  .setDescription(`Current: ${queue.playing.author} | ${queue.playing.title}`)
  .addFields(queue.tracks.map((track, i) => ({
    name: `${i + 1}. ${track.author} - ${track.title}`,
    value: `Requested by ${track.requestedBy.username}`
  })).slice(0, 10))
  .addField(queue.tracks.length > 10 ? `And ${queue.tracks.length - 10} more track(s)` : "This is the end of the queue!", "/u200B");
  
message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] }); // or message.channel.send(embed) if using discord.js v12
```

Go ahead and tweak it to your needs.

Also if you were wondering, the `/u200B` is there because you aren't allowed to have a  blank value in an embed, so that character code is used to render a blank character instead.